# Refraction shader in a specific mesh (LibGDX or openGL)

Tags: opengl, libgdx, shader

I'm programming on LibGDX, i'm a little bit stuck for my game because I want to create a water reffraction as the video [Procedural water](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uhMAHpV_cDg). To achieve that we must get the texture behind the water mesh into the the sampler2D to deform it. But i'm applying it on a curved mesh :

[Water special mesh](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hB8oh.png)

so for the sampler2D I've tried to learn a little about frameBuffer, but I think it's only for rectangular textures. Here it's a random texture load in the sampler2D. I give you my code for the mesh :

```
Mesh water = new Mesh(true, segments*2 + 2, 0, 
        new VertexAttribute(Usage.Position, 2, "a_position"),
        new VertexAttribute(Usage.ColorUnpacked, 4, "a_color"),
        new VertexAttribute(Usage.TextureCoordinates, 2, "a_texCoords"));
    
float theta = angle/segments;
    
float[] vertices = new float[(segments)*8*2];
    
for(int i = 0; i < segments*16; i += 16) {
        
    vertices[i ] = (float) (planetX + (planetRadius*Math.cos((i/16)*theta + startAngle)));
    vertices[i + 1] = (float) (planetY + (planetRadius*Math.sin((i/16)*theta + startAngle)));
    vertices[i + 2] = 0f;
    vertices[i + 3] = 1f;
    vertices[i + 4] = 1f;
    vertices[i + 5] = 1f;
    vertices[i + 6] = (i*1.0f)/(16.0f*segments);
    vertices[i + 7] = 0.0f;
        
    vertices[i + 8] = (float) (planetX + ((planetRadius - depth)*Math.cos((i/16)*theta + startAngle)));
    vertices[i + 9] = (float) (planetY + ((planetRadius - depth)*Math.sin((i/16)*theta + startAngle)));
    vertices[i + 10] = 0f;
    vertices[i + 11] = 1f;
    vertices[i + 12] = 1f;
    vertices[i + 13] = 1f;
    vertices[i + 14] = (i*1.0f)/(16.0f*segments);
    vertices[i + 15] = 1.0f;
        
}
    
water.setVertices(vertices);
shader.bind();
shader.setUniformMatrix("u_projTrans", batch.getProjectionMatrix());
shader.setUniformf("time", (float) time);
water.render(shader, GL20.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP);
```

And for the shader the same as the video

```
#ifdef GL_ES
precision mediump float;
#endif 

varying vec4 v_color;
varying vec2 v_texCoords;

uniform sampler2D texture;
uniform float time;

float rand(vec2 coord){
    return fract(sin(dot(coord, vec2(12.9898, 78.233)))* 43758.5453123);
}

float noise(vec2 coord){
    vec2 i = floor(coord);
    vec2 f = fract(coord);

    // 4 corners of a rectangle surrounding our point
    float a = rand(i);
    float b = rand(i + vec2(1.0, 0.0));
    float c = rand(i + vec2(0.0, 1.0));
    float d = rand(i + vec2(1.0, 1.0));

    vec2 cubic = f * f * (3.0 - 2.0 * f);

    return mix(a, b, cubic.x) + (c - a) * cubic.y * (1.0 - cubic.x) + (d - b) * cubic.x * cubic.y;
}

void main(){
    
    vec2 noisecoord1 = v_texCoords * 8.0;
    vec2 noisecoord2 = v_texCoords * 8.0 + 4.0;
    
    vec2 motion1 = vec2(time * 0.4, time * -0.5);
    vec2 motion2 = vec2(time * 0.3, time * 0.5);
    
    vec2 distort1 = vec2(noise(noisecoord1 + motion1), noise(noisecoord2 + motion1)) - vec2(0.5);
    vec2 distort2 = vec2(noise(noisecoord1 + motion2), noise(noisecoord2 + motion2)) - vec2(0.5);
    
    vec2 distort_sum = (distort1 + distort2)/60.0;
    
    vec4 color = texture2D(texture, v_texCoords + distort_sum, 0.0);
    vec4 blue = vec4(200/255, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    color = mix(color, blue, 0.3);
    color.rgb = mix(vec3(0.5), color.rgb, 1.4);
    
    float near_top = (v_texCoords.y + distort_sum.y) / (0.25);
    near_top = clamp(near_top, 0.0, 1.0);
    near_top = 1.0 - near_top;
    
    color = mix(color, vec4(1.0), near_top);
    
    float edge_lower = 0.6;
    float edge_upper = edge_lower + 0.1;
    
    if(near_top > edge_lower){
        color.a = 0.0;
        
        if(near_top < edge_upper){
            color.a = (edge_upper - near_top)/(edge_upper - edge_lower);
        }
    }
    
    gl_FragColor = color;
    
}
```

So is it possible to get the texture behind the mesh ?

Thanks a lot for your anwsers